# Can I convert string to a date in *ngFor?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using Angular with the PrimeNg library I have this component:

```
<td *ngFor="let item of items">
  <p-calendar
    showTime="true"
    [(ngModel)]="item.testDate">
   </p-calendar>
</td>
```

I am getting the value `item.testDate` from my database in the form of a string. However I need it to be of type Date.

Is there a way I can do that with something like an angular expression. Something like: `[(ngModel)]="new Date(item.testDate)"`

Or baring that how else can I convert this string to a Date?

Comment: Create a custom Pipe which will take your string as input and return date object.

https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: @Gauravjoshi that worked. I created a simple pipe that returned a date. I needed to use just the property binding of `[ngModel]` rather than the combined property and event binding `[(ngModel)]` but that's simple enough to work around. If you post your comment as and answer I'll select it. Thanks

Comment: Glad it works, No need to mark any answer :), Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

What i suggest is you need to convert it to Date in your service (by the time you get the data, convert it), controller or filter, not your view. Keep your view simple.

Comment: I thought of that. I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to do it since the data is fetched using HttpClient as an array of objects and it is just the one value I need to convert to a date. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Angular has an inbuilt date pipe which can convert 1. A date object 2. A number or 3. an ISO string into a date value according to locale rules. I guess this is what you intend to do since you haven't cleared this in the question.

It can be used as

```
{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}
```

For more reference [Angular Data Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: It's actually the other way around. I am trying to convert a string to a date not a date to a string as is done with the date pipe

Comment: My apologies. Maybe you can convert the string into a date object by passing the date as such :  `dateObject=new Date((this.year)+"-"+(this.MonthNum+1)+"-"+testData)` However this would be done in your .ts file or service file and store the result in an array and ngFor through that array ?

Answer (score 0):

**I think you have to use angular date pipe.
But you can't use it in ngModel directly.**

Ex;

```
<td *ngFor="let item of items">
  <p-calendar showTime="true" [(ngModel)]="(item.testDate | date:'fullDate')" 
     (ngModelChange)="item.testDate = $event">
  </p-calendar>
</td>
```

Please refer for the date type this link: 
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe